# Use output from awk as input for mv

Tags: awk, find, osx, pipe, rename

I'm trying to write a script (or a one-liner) that finds all image files with small dimensions and then moves them into a directory.  Based on [this answer from Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/583954/640438), I was able to generate a list of files with both dimensions lower than 500, and then [I was able to find all common images files as well as `.jpg`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23770184/5544691).

```
find -E . -regex ".*\.(jpg|gif|png|jpeg)" -type f -exec identify -format '%w %h %i\n' '{}' \; | awk '$1<500 && $2<500' | awk '{print $3}'
```

The second `awk` is so that it only prints the file name, which I was hoping to use in the input to `mv`.  **How can I get that output into `mv`?**

---

Sample output of the first `awk` is:

```
123 456 ./smallimage.jpg
333 333 ./square.png
```

The second `awk` just gives out

```
./smallimage.jpg
./square.png
```

However, I can't seem to find a way to get this list of filenames as the input for an `mv` command, as the desired resulting final command is some form of `mv <file list> ./small_images/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incorporate `mv` into `awk` using the `system()` function:

```
awk '$1<500 && $2<500 {system("mv "$3" /destination")}
```

Change the `mv` command to meet your need, here i have used:

```
mv /file_(third_field)_from_awk /destination
```

Also you don't need multiple `awk`s, only one would suffice as shown above.

Comment: That's good, but please consider that some filenames could contain spaces, which can break the `system()` call.

Comment: That worked! Thanks for the fast answer; turning `$3` into `substr($3,3)` (and testing by turning `system` to `print`) gave almost exactly the result I wanted.  The only other thing I'd want to do is make the regex ignore subdirectories and case-insensitive to the file extension.

Comment: My final one-liner ended up as `find -E . -iregex ".*\.(jpg|gif|png|jpeg|bmp)" -type f -exec identify -format '%w %h %i\n' '{}' \; | awk '$1<500 && $2<500 {system("mv "substr($3,3)" small_images/"substr($3,3)"")}'`.  You could add more image formats if you really wanted to, but I'm pretty sure I don't have any tga or tiff files that I'm interested in.

Answer (score 1):

With the assumption that you are not having filenames with embedded newlines, you can use the GNU `mv` and `xargs` programs to do this.

```
 ... | awk ... | xargs -d'\n' mv -t ./small_images
```

xargs collects the filenames from the input and appends them onto the `mv -t ./small_images` command, splitting very long commands as needed. You need a version of `mv` that has the `-t` option to specify the destination directory at the start of the command, or else write a tiny script to handle it.

Comment: How would that handle files in subdirectories or those already moved?